# Repeated elements without list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so here is my code:

```
y=[]
for x in random_gen:
    y.append(x)   
print([x for x, count in collections.Counter(y).x() if count > 1])
```

Is there anyway of doing this without appending the list i.e. without `y.append(x)` ?

Comment: Change `Counter(y)` to `Counter(random_gen)`

Comment: Since `y` is just a copy of `random_gen`

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `y = list(random_gen)` ?

Answer (score 2):

What this loop does:

```
y=[]
for x in random_gen:
  y.append(x)
```

is basically make a copy of `random_gen` and call it `y`.

So instead, just use `random_gen`:

```
print([x for x, count in collections.Counter(random_gen).x() if count > 1])
```

Then you don't even need the loop. This was taken from Barmar's comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
y=[]   
print([x for x, count in collections.Counter(random_gen).x() if count > 1])
```

Because `y` is just a copy of `ramdom_gen`